# Angular routing navigation won't work inside the tap operator

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is the `signIn` method, it's not complete but it used to work until I made some refactoring (now the guards return `Observable`s):

```
  public signInWithGooglePopup(): any {
    this.firebaseAuthService.setMediaProvider(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
    this.firebaseAuthService.signInWithPopup()
        .pipe
        (
          tap(() => this.router.navigate(['home'])),
          map(userCredential => new FirebaseUser().deserialize(userCredential.user)),
          switchMap(firebaseUser => this.firebaseUserService.update(firebaseUser))
        ).subscribe();
  }
```

Seems like after that piece of refactoring the navigation went to the dogs...I don't get why.

After I click my `Sign In` button the url stays the same even though I can  access the home page (the one I'm supposed to be navigated to) by typing its url in the address bar. That's the navigation that does not work. what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Here is the logic inside the authentication guard:

```
    return this.firebaseAuthService.isSignedIn().pipe(
      map(
        isLoggedIn => {
          if (isLoggedIn) {
            return true;
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['sign-in']);
            return false;
          }
        }
      )
    );
```

Comment: If you type console.log instead of navigate method, will you see the output?

Comment: @cuddlemeister Yep, if I change `this.router.navigate(['home'])` to `console.log('home')`, I do see `home` in the console.

Comment: try `tap(_ => setTimeout(_ => this.router.navigate(['home']), 0))`

Comment: do you get any errors in your console? I suppose you may need to add a leading slash in the route `this.router.navigate(['/home']`

Comment: @Antediluvian No, it did not change anything... Seems like the whole issue has something to do with the part I refactored, I will provide more information on that a bit later.

Comment: @C_Ogoo Nah, it used to work like that and as far as I remember in the doc they don't recommend using slashes in cases like this. The router is smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: Do you have a guard watching the route where you try to navigate? In my code, I had a similar issue and realized that it was not the `tap`'s fault, but some properties were not correctly updated and thus, the guard stopped the navigation.